# How to fix NeoSolarized red coloured brackets

Tags: colors, neovim, treesitter

I have switched over to using NeoVim and the colorscheme which I have decided to use is [NeoSolarized](https://github.com/overcache/NeoSolarized), as well as this I also installed treesitter to improve the syntax highlighting, and I have installed the c++ parser successfully by running `TSInstall cpp`, however I have run into a slight issue which is that now all of my brackets and paranthesis and semi-colons are colored red:
[image: Image of how the braces look like inside of Neovim]

I wanted to know if there was a way for me to get rid of these red coloured colored brackets and semicolons so that I can turn them back into a grey colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this through adding the following line of code to my `init.vim`

```
hi Delimiter guifg=#839496
```

Comment: Yes this is a better option than mine for the required use in context

Answer (score 2):

what you probably  need is

```
MatchParen cterm=bold ctermbg=none ctermfg=grey
```

put this in your vimrc file.
often in (~/.vim/colors/)

basically, `cterm` determines the style, which can be none, underline or bold, and `ctermfg` is foreground colors (hence `fg`, backround is `bg`), so you can change them when you need.